# How to install IronPython 3 on Windows 10, to be used by Visual Studio VB.NET app?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, visual-studio, ironpython

How can I get Iron Python 3 installed on Windows 10 so that my Visual Studio 2017 pro shows it in its Tools Menu > Python > Python Environments?

I easily installed Iron Python 2 from http://ironpython.codeplex.com/
My Python Environments then shows IronPython 2.7

But for IronPython3, I tried  GitHub  >  IronLanguages > ironpython3
downloaded it to:
ironpython3-master\

Nothing was installed, so I tried:
ironpython3-master\IronPython.sln  but got build errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to their GitHub Builds of IronPython 3 are not yet provided.